# BGL concurrent read accesses problem

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, boost-graph

I need to iterate over the vertices and edges of a BGL adjacency_list from several threads.
Which would be an efficient way to do that, provided that the graph is large (mutex..)?

The BGL methods don't support reentrant calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BGL is [currently not thread safe](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/05/167356.php). Take a look at [MTGL](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/mtgl) which provides a BGL like interface but is designed for massively multithreaded platforms.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you aren't modifying the graph structure, multiple concurrent reads are safe; updates and writes to properties require locking.  The page that was linked is about algorithms running in parallel, which they currently don't in plain BGL.